# Typescript: generic function to provide typesafe access to variable not exported from module

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a module with an object containing a cache of items of different types, each stored in a property of the cache object:

```
type Pet = { name: string, petFood: string }
type Human = { firstName: string, lastName: string }
type Cache = { pets: Pet[], humans: Human[] }
const theCache: Cache = {pets: [], humans: []}
```

I have a function to retrieve data from the cache. It  takes in a key, representing a property of the cache (i.e. `pets` or `humans`), and a generic type specifying the type of data I expect that property to return (i.e. `Pet` or `Human`). I can use conditional types to achieve type safety here:

```
// Alias for all properties of TObj which return a TResult
export type PropertiesOfType<TObj, TResult> = {
    [K in keyof TObj]: TObj[K] extends TResult ? K : never
}[keyof TObj]

function readCache<T, K extends PropertiesOfType<Cache, T[]>, C extends { [key in K]: T[] }>(
    key: K, cache: C
): T[] {
    return cache[key]
}

const pets: Pet[] = readCache("pets", theCache) // Compiles - this is correct
const wrongType: Human[] = readCache("pets", theCache) // Doesn't compile - this is correct
```

Within the module that all works fine, as I can pass `theCache` into the `readCache` function. However, `theCache` is not exported as I want to keep it private to the module. Instead, I want to export a function that other modules can call to get read-only access to data in the cache, e.g. something like this:

```
export function getCachedItems<T, K extends PropertiesOfType<Cache, T[]>>(key: K): T[] {
    return readCache(key, theCache) // Doesn't compile
}
```

The problem is that the code above doesn't compile:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Cache' is not assignable to
parameter of type '{ [key in K]: T[]; }'
```

Is there a way I can get the code to compile (without having to do an unsafe cast)?

**UPDATE**: Titian Cernicova-Dragomir made two great suggestions:

1. Return `Cache[K]`. This works fine for places where I want to call the method and know the type I'm working with. But in cases where I have another generic function which wants to call the generic `getCachedItems`, and know that what it gets back is an array of `T`, that won't work.
2. Return `Cache[K][number][]`. This solves the above problem (and answers the original question). But this only works when the cache contains arrays. What if I want the cache object to be slightly different (more like a Dictionary or Map in other languages): each entry in the cache should itself be another object, with a property for each item which it caches, where the name of the property is some ID of that object, [as suggested when designing a Redux store](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#designing-a-normalized-state).

In other words I'd have this:

```
export type Map<T> = { [key: string]: T }
export type Cache = { pets: Map<Pet>, humans: Map<Human> }
const theCache: Cache = {pets: {}, humans: {}}

function readCache<T, K extends PropertiesOfType<Cache, Map<T>>, C extends { [key in K]: Map<T> }>(
    key: K, cache: C
): Map<T> {
    return cache[key]
}

const pets: Map<Pet> = readCache("pets", theCache) // Compiles - this is correct
const wrongType: Map<Human> = readCache("pets", theCache) // Doesn't compile - this is correct

export function getCachedItems<T, K extends PropertiesOfType<Cache, Map<T>>>(key: K): Map<T> {
    return readCache(key, theCache) // Doesn't compile
}
```

So I still get the original problem that way. If I try the suggestion of returning `C[K]`, again, it works if I know the type when calling it, but not in a generic function:

```
function readCache<T, K extends keyof C, C extends { [key in K]: Map<T> }>(
    key: K, cache: C
): C[K] {
    return cache[key]
}

const pets: Map<Pet> = readCache("pets", theCache) // Compiles - this is correct
const wrongType: Map<Human> = readCache("pets", theCache) // Doesn't compile - this is correct

export function getCachedItems<T, K extends keyof Cache>(key: K): Cache[K] {
    return readCache(key, theCache)
}

const pets2: Map<Pet> = getCachedItems("pets") // Compiles - this is correct
const wrongType2: Map<Human> = getCachedItems("pets") // Doesn't compile - this is correct

function callerInAnotherModule<T, K extends keyof Cache>(key: K) {
    const expected : Map<T> = getCachedItems(key) // Doesn't compile
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional types that still contain unresolved type parameters are usually a a problem as the compiler can't expand them.

If `cache` only contains relevant keys an approach that works better is to use index type queries, they produce the same results in this case but are more friendly to the compiler.

```
type Pet = { name: string, petFood: string }
type Human = { firstName: string, lastName: string }
type Cache = { pets: Pet[], humans: Human[] }
const theCache: Cache = {pets: [], humans: []}

function readCache<K extends keyof C, C extends { [key in K]: any[] }>(
    key: K, cache: C
): C[K] {
    return cache[key]
}

const pets: Pet[] = readCache("pets", theCache) // Compiles - this is correct
const wrongType: Human[] = readCache("pets", theCache)

export function getCachedItems<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K): Cache[K]  {
    return readCache(key, theCache) // ok
}
```

While the answer above works, the request in the comments is to be able to treat the result of `readCache` as an array. While `Cache[K]` is a union of arrays, its methods are mangled and hard to use. We can drill down one more level and get the item type from `Cache[K]` using `Cache[K][number]` and use this as the array item in the result. This will make arrays work well in methods like `getCachedItems`:

```
type Pet = { id: string; name: string, petFood: string }
type Human = { id: string; firstName: string, lastName: string }
type Cache = { pets: Pet[], humans: Human[] }
const theCache: Cache = {pets: [], humans: []}

function readCache<K extends keyof C, C extends { [key in K]: any[] }>(
    key: K, cache: C
): C[K][number][] {
    return cache[key]
}

const pets: Pet[] = readCache("pets", theCache) // Compiles - this is correct

export function getCachedItems<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K): Cache[K][number][]  {
    return readCache(key, theCache) // ok
}

export function getCachedItemsAndMap<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K)  {
    return readCache(key, theCache)
        .map(o => ({  // map works fine
            id: o.id, // we can even access common members
            item: o
        }));
}
```

**Edit**

Version with the `Map` type added to the question:

```
type Pet = { name: string, petFood: string }
type Human = { firstName: string, lastName: string }

export type Map<T> = { [key: string]: T }
export type Cache = { pets: Map<Pet>, humans: Map<Human> }
const theCache: Cache = {pets: {}, humans: {}}


function readCache<K extends keyof C, C extends { [key in K]: Map<any> }>(
    key: K, cache: C
): Map<C[K][string]> {
    return cache[key]
}

const pets: Map<Pet> = readCache("pets", theCache) // Compiles - this is correct

export function getCachedItems<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K): Map<Cache[K][string]>  {
    return readCache(key, theCache) // ok
}

export function getCachedItemsAndMap<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K)  {
    let cache: Map<Cache[K][string]> = readCache(key, theCache)
}
```

**Edit v2**

Actually I don't think the whole is needed since there are no relevant methods on the `Map` you want to access. This also works:

```
type Pet = { name: string, petFood: string }
type Human = { firstName: string, lastName: string }

export type Map<T> = { [key: string]: T }
export type Cache = { pets: Map<Pet>, humans: Map<Human> }
const theCache: Cache = {pets: {}, humans: {}}


function readCache<K extends keyof C, C extends { [key in K]: Map<any> }>(
    key: K, cache: C
): C[K] {
    return cache[key]
}

const pets: Map<Pet> = readCache("pets", theCache) // Compiles - this is correct

export function getCachedItems<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K): Cache[K]  {
    return readCache(key, theCache) // ok
}

export function getCachedItemsAndMap<K extends keyof Cache>(key: K)  {
    let cache: Cache[K] = readCache(key, theCache)
    let a = cache[''] // Pet | Human
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. I was using this approach originally but it poses a slightly different problem. If I want to call `getCachedItems` from another function which also takes in `K` and `T`, in that other function I can't assume that what I get back from `getCachedItems` an array of `T` (as far as the compiler is concerned it's just `Cache[K]` which could be anything. I know that in my cache every property contains an array so I need to be able to treat it as such.

Comment: @YoniGibbs how about returning `Cache[K][number][]`. The will let you treat the result as an array (even with the original the members are there just they are a bit mangled) but it is essentially equivalent.

Comment: @YoniGibbs updated the answer with the version I suggested above, seems to work well, let me know if you have any other issues with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Titian. You've definitely answered my original question. But I've expanded it a bit, as in actual fact the use of an array was just an example. If you have thoughts on the expanded question, please do share. Also, see that syntax: `Cache[K][number][]` - that's a new one on me. What exactly is it? Has it got some name I can google to go off and read about it?

Comment: @YoniGibbs it's an index type query, just like `Cache[K]` where `K` is an index of `Cache`. Since `Cache[K]` is an array, it is index-able by `number` so  `Cache[K][number]` will return the item type of the array

Comment: @YoniGibbs the equivalent to `Cache[K][number][]` for the map type you used above would be `Map<Cache[K][string]>`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thanks very much!